# Ошибка создания таблицы SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создаю таблицу в SQL Server:

```
USE ##gz;
GO
CREATE TABLE mt(
[num_notice] NCHAR(50),
[num_contract] NCHAR(50),
[fz] NCHAR(50),
[name_customer] NCHAR(4000),
[inn_customer] NCHAR(50),
[kpp_customer] NCHAR(50),
[tel_customer] NCHAR(50),
[mail_customer] NCHAR(50),
[name_producer] NCHAR(4000),
[inn_producer] NCHAR(50),
[kpp_producer] NCHAR(50),
[tel_producer] NCHAR(50),
[mail_producer] NCHAR(50),
[product] NVARCHAR(MAX),
[okpd2] NCHAR(50),
[product_price] FLOAT,
[qnt] FLOAT,
[unit] NCHAR(50),
[cost] FLOAT,
[delivery_region] NVARCHAR(MAX),
[date_start_buy] NCHAR(1000),
[date_stop_request] NCHAR(1000),
[date_contract] NCHAR(1000),
[date_delivery] NCHAR(1000),
[status] NCHAR(100),
[contract_price] FLOAT,
[currency] NCHAR(100),
[qnt_conract] INT,
[ident_code] NCHAR(100),
[year] INT,
[month] INT,
[day] INT,
[region_customer] NCHAR(4000),
[region_producer] NCHAR (4000),
[class] NCHAR(1000),
[type] NCHAR(1000))
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
Сообщение 1701, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 3
Ошибка создания или изменения таблицы "mt", так как минимальный размер строки равен 45959, включая 11 байт внутренней дополнительной памяти. Это превышает максимально допустимый размер строки таблицы, 8060 байт.
```

Как исправить и в чем ошибка
Спасибо.

Comment: _максимально допустимый размер строки таблицы 8060 байт_ - это и есть ответ. Самый простой способ преодолеть ограничение - использовать `NVARCHAR` вместо `NCHAR`.

Comment: [Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186981(v=sql.105))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `максимально допустимый размер строки таблицы 8060 байт` - это и есть
>   ответ. Самый простой способ преодолеть ограничение - использовать
>   NVARCHAR вместо NCHAR

Помогло. Сократил количество типов данных, где мог проставил NVARCHAR.